# Frenet equation applicability

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, curves, frenet-frame

The Frenet - orthogonal basis $(t, n, b)$ at $t0$.But $t,n$ are orthogonal only for unit speed curve. So is there any method for general curves without unit speed reparametrization.

I found that in some cases finding unit speed makes the equation more clumsy.

Comment: There are formulas for computing the Frenet frame when given an arbitrary parametrization. I don't know if that's what you're looking for...

Comment: You need to apply the chain rule. I suggest you read section 1.2 of [my text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf), where you'll find lots of examples of this.